# Программа зависает из-за schedule

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt, schedule

Подскажите, работаю с библиотекой `datetime` и `schedule`.
В определенное время должна сработать функция.
Для этого использую `schedule`.

Я использую *PyQt5* и при запуске этого самого `schedule` окно зависает (написано "Не отвечает") и кликать на кнопки в окне нельзя.
Только ждать, пока `schedule` закончится.
Смысл программы в том, что если ты указываешь время (например **14:50**) и нажимаешь на кнопку, то программа должна в **14:50** вывести сообщение.
Поэтому использую `schedule`.

Но повторюсь, окно зависает, а хотелось бы пока идет цикл, в окне нажимать и на другие кнопки.
После **14:50** и вывода сообщения программа отвисает и можно дальше кликать куда хочу, но пока выполняется schedule до **14:50** - кликать не получается, всё зависает./

Скажите, как избавиться от зависания?

UPDATE  (запускаете, указываете время на 1 или более минут больше от текущего и ждете, пока время не будет одинаковым: по МСК и то, которое указали

```
import sys
import time
from datetime import datetime

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt5 import uic

import schedule


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(449, 208)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 40, 191, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(11)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(250, 50, 171, 21))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(340, 130, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 449, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Когда вывести сообщение:"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Запуститть"))


class Example(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.go)
        self.f = False

    def write(self):
        print('красафчик')
        self.f = True

    def go(self):
        try:
            self.t = self.lineEdit.text()
            self.datetime_object = datetime.strptime(self.t, '%H:%M')
            print(self.datetime_object.time())
            print(datetime.now().time())
            print(self.datetime_object.time() == datetime.now().time())

            if self.datetime_object.time() > datetime.now().time():
                schedule.every().day.at(str(self.datetime_object.time())).do(
                    self.write)
                while self.f != True:
                    print('нет')
                    schedule.run_pending()
                    time.sleep(1)

            while self.f != True:
                if self.datetime_object.time() == datetime.now().time():
                    schedule.every().day.at(
                        str(self.datetime_object.time())).do(self.write())
                schedule.run_pending()
                time.sleep(0.5)

        except Exception as e:
            print(e)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    ex = Example()
    ex.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: `schedule` запускайте в отдельном потоке, насколько я помню, для его работы нужен бесконечный цикл, а при запуске его в главном потоке, цикл обработки событий приложения остановится. Либо используйте в главном потоке но вместо цикла используйте `QTimer`, А так, добавьте минимальный код с проблемой :)

Comment: @gil9red обновил с кодом. Пока выполняется цикл, окно "неприкасаемо". 
И вот вопрос, где написать цикл для schedule, чтобы во время цикла можно было также пользоваться окном и не была надпись "Не отвечает"?
А задача в том, чтобы в указанное время вывелось сообщение "красафчик"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вызов `time.sleep` в коде вкупе с бесконечным циклом блокирует обработку событий приложения, поэтому оно не реагирует.

Самое быстрое решение без минимума изменения кода через использование `QApplication.processEvents()` вместо `time.sleep`:

```
...
            if self.datetime_object.time() > datetime.now().time():
                schedule.every().day.at(str(self.datetime_object.time())).do(
                    self.write
                )
                while not self.f:
                    # print('нет')
                    schedule.run_pending()
                    QApplication.processEvents()

            while not self.f:
                if self.datetime_object.time() == datetime.now().time():
                    schedule.every().day.at(
                        str(self.datetime_object.time())).do(self.write())
                schedule.run_pending()
                QApplication.processEvents()
...
```

Вызов `QApplication.processEvents()` дает возможность обработать события приложения, возвращая ему активность.

---

Другой вариант -- отправить работу `schedule` в отдельный поток, накидал пример через `QThread` и сигналы:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, pyqtSignal

...

class ScheduleThread(QThread):
    about_time = pyqtSignal(str)

    def add_time(self, time: str):
        schedule.every().day.at(time).do(
            lambda: self.about_time.emit(time)
        )

    def run(self):
        while True:
            schedule.run_pending()
            time.sleep(1)


class Example(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.go)

        self.thread = ScheduleThread()
        self.thread.about_time.connect(self.write)
        self.thread.start()

    def write(self, time: str):
        print('красафчик', time)

    def go(self):
        try:
            t = self.lineEdit.text()
            datetime_object = datetime.strptime(t, '%H:%M')
            time_str = str(datetime_object.time())

            self.thread.add_time(time_str)

        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

Answer (score 3):

Вам не нужны никакие дополнительные библиотеки и дополнительные потоки для вашей задачи. Попробуйте так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt5 import uic
#from datetime import datetime
#import schedule
#import time


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(449, 208)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 40, 191, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(11)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(250, 50, 171, 21))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(340, 130, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 449, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Когда вывести сообщение:"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Запуститть"))


class Example(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.go)
        self.lineEdit.setPlaceholderText('Введите время ЧЧ:ММ:СС')
        
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        self.timer.setInterval(1000)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.timerHit)

    def timerHit(self):
        current_time = QtCore.QTime.currentTime().toString()
        time = self.lineEdit.text()
        print(time, current_time)
        if time <= current_time:
            msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(
                self, 
                'ВНИМАНИЕ', 
                'Пришло время, делайте что-нибудь!') 
            self.timer.stop()
        
    def go(self):
        self.timer.start()
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Главное, чтобы проверка секунды в секунды уложилась :)

Comment: @gil9red я учел ваше предложение